# can't create object instace using irb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb

I try to create User instance of my user model in irb. but it gives me this error

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > u = User.new
NameError: uninitialized constant User
from (irb):1
from /home/darshana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

irb doesn't loads rails for you.

try `bundle exec rails console`